# Moving node in QGIS?

Tags: editing, vertices, qgis-3, nodes

I am trying to move a vertex in QGIS 3.2. I can select nodes in QGIS 3.2 (which show up blue), but every time I try to move it with the node tool it just deselects the vertex.

How do I move a node in QGIS 3.2?

[image]

Comment: No more drag and drop, only one click an place it where you want

Comment: Im using QGIS 3.6.0 and I can't move a node too .. I've followed all your advices, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do is to click once to select the vertex (node) and move your mouse to move the vertex and when you finish click again to deselect the vertex (node). The detailed explanation is in this answer: [Editing vertex in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285846/editing-vertex-in-qgis-3/285849?noredirect=1#comment484320_285849), which I think you have seen it before.

- Put your mouse on the vertex you want to edit, and it will be highlighted in big red circle

[image]

- Click on the vertex only once and then move the vertex

[image]

- When you finish click again to release (deselect) the vertex

[image]

- Then save the edits

**Update**

I tested your data and everything goes well. I do not have the same issue you have. I loaded your data into the canvas, clicked on start editing, selected the node editing tool, and I could move the node without any problem.

Here is your data:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Try to load your data in a new QGIS project, and start editing again. If it did not work, then uninstall QGIS 3.2 completely from your machine and reinstall it again. The current version is QGIS 3.4.

Comment: This doesn't work though - I just get blue circles and every time I click the circle it becomes deselected.

Comment: @user1655130 I cannot reproduce your issue, when you click on the blue node can you delete it? It might be an invalid geometry. By the way, I am using shapefile, try to change the format of your layer to shapefile if it is not.

Comment: I know the geometry is valid but it still doesnt work. See image in my original post of what I get.

Comment: Yes, I am able to delete a node but that is it.

Comment: Can you share a small portion of your file so that I can test it?

Comment: How do I upload data on this platform?

Comment: You can use any drive like Google, drive upload the data there, and share the link at this website.

Comment: Ok cool - here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x9l_FiLoab6kD7ZAucdShqMO9lW3Fq6P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For moving point features, I had to right-click on the point feature to highlight it in the vertex editor, then left click to pick the location of the feature, and then another left-click at the new location to make the move. (QGIS 3.32.3 on a Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in QGIS 3.12. For me it was solved by resetting the snapping options (under Project > Snapping options).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My project CRS had switched to a pseudo mercator. When I changed the project crs from pseudo to a specific non-global mercator (in my case EPSG 32632) I was able to adjust my polygon nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If the layer in which you want to edit the vertices has symbology, sometimes QGIS seems to only allow you to select the vertex (shown with a blue circle), but not to move it.
I solve this situation by removing the layer symbology or changing to another simple symbology. Then the vertex editing tool works correctly and you can move the node...